# What are some pre-built classes like in Bootstrap which provide animation?

Tags: css

I am making a web page. I know html, CSS3 and Bootstrap and I want to provide animations to it. So is there any pre-built class present by the use of which I can provide animations in my navbar contents or body?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any pre-built classes from Bootstrap, but I'm using animate.css in my own projects. It's very easy to use. Just add the CSS classes you'd like to use.

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

```
<h1 class="animated bounce">Example</h1>
```